# Lazy Loading in EF4.0 is freezing UI

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm, .net-4.0, freeze

Hi I am designing an application using WPF, EF and MVVM (.NET4.0).

I face issue with freezing UI when I'm binding data. I think this is because of lazy loading.

MVVM:

```
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state =>
        {
                IsProgressBarVisible(true);

                var service = Context.SomeModel.ToList();
                BgServiceCompleted(service);
        });
```

XAML:

```
"{Binding OrderItemViews.SOmeModel_A.SomeModel_B.SOmeField}"
"{Binding OrderItemViews.Country.Name}"
```

Some Model:

```
public class SomeModel_A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ....        
    public int SomeB_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SomeModel_B SomeModel_B { get; set; }
}
```

I found a solution for this problem.

1) setting the IsAsync-Property in the ItemsSource-Binding.

```
"{Binding OrderItemViews.SOmeModel_A.SomeModel_B.SOmeField, IsAsync=true}"
```

The interface does not freeze, but the value appears after a while time. This will confuse some users.

2) using Include for loading include data.
For instance:

```
Context.SomeModel.Include(a => a.SomeModel2).Load();
```

but in my case Context doesn't have **Include**. Why?

Which the best way to solve this problem?

Could you please give me a guidance on how should I do that or any useful resource I can read and learn about it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx) is not part of the standard libraries, you have to add `using System.Data.Entity;`. Failing that, what is the type returned by `Context.SomeModel`?

Comment: thanks, I'm  included system.data.entity and "Include extention method" appeared. What about type which return COntext, does it matter? (Array of {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SomeMOdel_...)